# Debugging the C/C++ runtime libraries on Linux and seeing the library code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging

When writing C++ in Visual Studio 2012 I can step in to the actual Microsoft implementations of functions like malloc() etc.

What is the best (debugger?) to use when on Linux and can I step in to the Linux/GCC implementations of functions like malloc()? Is it relatively simple to do? I'd like to get to know what is actually happening "under the hood" in terms of Linux, when writing C++ on Linux.

Comment: Look at glibc's source code.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I don't want to do this "offline" through, I want to do it as I step through the code- not by opening files and statically reading the content.

Comment: You could also install the debug variant of packages like  `libc6-dbg` etc etc....

Comment: Maybe what you could do is download glibc's source, code your program against that source instead of the gcc provided one, then you should be able to step through in `gdb` because it is now in _your_ program.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your enviroment i would say **yes** it is simple. but it is really depending on your setup. so what are you going to use?

most *debuggers* on on linux relying on [gdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) and are just gui's for it. if you are going to use [QT](http://qt-project.org/) for example, it is realy easy/simple to do what you want. you also could use [ddd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger) which is also just a gui for gdb, or gdb itself in a terminal. the only hitch can (should not) happen is that you have to say your debugger where to find the source of the lib you want to *jump in* while debugging. also the source should be on your system (on a debian (and offsprings like ubuntu) usually the *-dev or from the source repositories the source itself).

additional gdb is possible to walk-through the catch block of a try-catch, which isn't possible under visual studio. in my opinion this is a real candy for code debugging... also gdb is possible to debug executables created with clang.